# Error when Converting .py to .exe with cx_freeze

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, exe, cx-freeze

I am trying to convert my .py code to .exe. I tried all the options from posts on here and on the web, and all I could up with was the error below when I used cx_Freeze, and the .exe not opening when I used pyinstaller. 
can someone help with the error below or give an alternative that works?
PS: my py code is actually ipython code from my jupyter notebook, but I'm trying not to share the code source.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working while using pyinstaller, the key was to open the .exe file from the command window to be able to see the warning, which was "Import cv2 not found" after I deleted that line(since I was not using that module) and re built it, the .exe file now works. Hope this will help someone one day